# Differences between events on iOS calendar and Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Im working with google App Scripts for my final project in a computer Science Degree, in particular I'm working with the google Calendar API. I've wrote some code that creates events and after a bunch of work I've noticed a problem: the events created by the code are different between google calendar and iOS calendar on my iPhone (calendar synced with google Account). I wrote a little piece of code to show an example of this problem.

all the code I wrote to create events always created right events on google calendar, not on ios Calendar (what I see on iOS calendar is different compared to what I see on google calendar). I'm wondering if this is an iOS sync probem or the problem is in my code.

```
//I want to create 2 events called 'iOS Event': on Wednesday and on Friday, in the week of the 8 of july.
function createiOSEvent() {
  var newCal;
  newCal = CalendarApp.createCalendar('iOS calendar');
  //I start the events on 8 of july, at 8:30 AM
  var startDate = new Date(2019,6,8);
  var hours = 8;
  var minutes = 30;
  startDate.setHours(hours);
  startDate.setMinutes(minutes);

  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence();
  var weekDays = [CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY,CalendarApp.Weekday.FRIDAY];
  recurrence.addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekdays(weekDays).times(2); //I set this 2 days of the week
  recurrence.addDateExclusion(startDate); //I don't want an event on the fist day, only on wednesday and friday

  newCal.createEventSeries('iOS Event', startDate, startDate, recurrence);

}
```

the expected results of this code are 2 events, created on wednesday, 10 of july and on Friday, 12 of July...in fact this is what I see in google calendar after executed the code. Conversely, On iOS, I see ONLY ONE event: the one on wednesday, 10 of july...no event on Friday 12. No error messages after execution (in fact, in google calendar I see the right events).   This is only one example of problems with different events between ios Caendar/google Calendar: sometimes ios Calendar duplicate some events, sometimes add some events, sometimes (like this one) remove some events.

Comment: I don't think you can create events on your IOS calendar with Google Apps Script.

Comment: Ios calendar is only synced with my google Account so it "imports" events by google calendar

Comment: Try Googling `my ios calendar is not syncing to google recurrent events` .  Evidently, there are some issues in this area.